# How do I expose a type imported from a required module?

Tags: powershell

in the following scenario, involving 2 modules, how do I expose the `test` type so it is available to `Get-Result` from `MainModule.psm1` ?

My current result is `Unable to find type [Test]`

**Scenario**

`MainModule` has `ReferenceModule` in its RequiredModules PSD1.

`MainModule` has a function called `Get-Result` who take the `test`class as parameter.

`ReferenceModule` contains the definition for the `test` class.

**Complete reproducible example**

```
$MyModulePSD1 = @"
@{
RootModule = 'MyModule.psm1'
ModuleVersion = '0.0.0.1'
GUID = '8428874a-381f-473a-b754-43304df5a219'
RequiredModules = @("$($Env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\MyModule\ReferenceModule.psd1")
FunctionsToExport  = '*'
}
"@

$ReferenceModulePSD1= @"
@{
RootModule = 'ReferenceModule.psm1'
ModuleVersion = '0.0.0.1'
GUID = '8428874a-381f-473a-b754-22222225a219'
FunctionsToExport  = '*'
}
"@


$MyModulePSM1 = @'
    Function Get-Result([Test]$MyParam) {
        return $true
    }
'@


$ReferenceModulePSM1 = @'
class test {
    [String]$test
}
'@

New-Item -Path "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\MyModule" -ItemType Directory -Force
New-Item -Path "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\ReferenceModule" -ItemType Directory -Force

Set-Content -Path "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\MyModule\MyModule.psd1" -Value $MyModulePSD1
Set-Content -Path "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\MyModule\MyModule.psm1" -Value $MyModulePSM1

Set-Content -Path "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\MyModule\ReferenceModule.psm1" -Value $ReferenceModulePSM1
Set-Content -Path "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\MyModule\ReferenceModule.psd1" -Value $ReferenceModulePSD1


Import-Module "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\MyModule\MyModule.psd1" -Force

Get-Result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reference the reference module using the 'using' keyword. Please note/edit my hard coded desktop folder. For some reason I can't explain it is not possible to use the `$Env:USERPROFILE` variable there.

```
$MyModulePSD1 = @"
@{
RootModule = 'MyModule.psm1'
ModuleVersion = '0.0.0.1'
GUID = '8428874a-381f-473a-b754-43304df5a219'
RequiredModules = @("$($Env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\MyModule\ReferenceModule.psd1")
FunctionsToExport  = '*'
}
"@

$ReferenceModulePSD1= @"
@{
RootModule = 'ReferenceModule.psm1'
ModuleVersion = '0.0.0.1'
GUID = '8428874a-381f-473a-b754-22222225a219'
FunctionsToExport  = '*'
}
"@


$MyModulePSM1 = @'
    using module 'C:\Users\gertjan\Desktop\MyModule\ReferenceModule.psm1'
    Function Get-Result([Test]$MyParam) {
    return $true
}
'@


$ReferenceModulePSM1 = @'
class test {
    [String]$test
}
'@

New-Item -Path "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\MyModule" -ItemType Directory -Force
New-Item -Path "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\ReferenceModule" -ItemType Directory -    Force

Set-Content -Path "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\MyModule\MyModule.psd1" -Value $MyModulePSD1
Set-Content -Path "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\MyModule\MyModule.psm1" -Value $MyModulePSM1

Set-Content -Path "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\MyModule\ReferenceModule.psm1" -Value $ReferenceModulePSM1
Set-Content -Path "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\MyModule\ReferenceModule.psd1" -Value $ReferenceModulePSD1


Import-Module "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\MyModule\MyModule.psd1" -Force

Get-Result
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ! Regarding variable in Using statement, this is a known fact apparently `Using module statement cannot include any variables. Its values must be static.` Source : https://info.sapien.com/index.php/scripting/scripting-classes/import-powershell-classes-from-modules

Comment: That's what I expected but didn't check. Thanks for checking.